# Problema con ejecutable de Python

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysqlconnector

creé una aplicación de python y la convertí en un ejecutable usando pyinstaller. El problema es que al ejecutarlo, me aparece el error: **ImportError: No localization support for language 'eng'** Según indica, aparece en la línea 34, cuando ejecuta el primer mysql.connector. No sé que causa el problema ya que cuando lo corro cómo archivo python en la terminal, todo funciona perfecto. Encontré una [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15893085/importerror-no-localization-support-for-language-eng-in-python) en SO en inglés pero la solución da a un enlace caído.  El código es largo, no sé si colocarlo ya que el problema no es de código en sí. Si alguien puede ayudarme, gracias.

```
#Línea del error, cuando corre desde la terminal no hay problema, solo en la aplicación.
conn=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="Baelca1", database="Lista_datos_Baelca")
```

Comment: *Encontré una respuesta en SO en inglés pero la solución da a un enlace caído.* Como habras notado, por eso insistimos en que la respuesta esté lo mas autocontenida posible (toda la info relevante dentro de la publicación de SO). Por cierto, pregunta, probaste con las otras respuestas???

Comment: @DanteS. Hola Dante, si. importé en el código esta línea: 'from mysql.connector.locales.eng import client_error' que es la segunda solución. Y ahora me da un error distinto en la misma linea (osea, la de la conexión) que lee: **mysql.connector.errors.NotSupportedError: Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' is not supported** Busqué otra solución para eso, pero tampoco funcionó.

Comment: @DanteS. Conoces otro foro donde pueda hacer estas preguntas?? El de Oracle no abre en venezuela

Comment: No se nada de foros, pero reddit podría ser una opción. Ademas, esto no es un foro. Si pudiera ayudarte, lo haría. Te deseo suerte!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sé si se habrá conseguido solucionar el segundo error que se tenía (*mysql.connector.errors.NotSupportedError: Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' is not supported*), pero lo único que hay que hacer es añadir otro import en el script de código. La sentencia es la siguiente:

```
import mysql.connector.plugins.mysql_native_password
```

Al menos a mí, después de solucionar este error, me funcionó todo correctamente.